# Put PHP img src inside string

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm looking at a PHP logic problem for me, but I can't fix it, so I ask you guys here. How can I call/combine the underneath PHP img with the var string method?

I would like to call an image with PHP:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/prev.gif'); ?>
```

But I would like to call the php from the following string:

```
var str_buffer = new String (
 "<table width=\"100%\">\n"+
    "<tr>\n <td>\n"+
    "<img src=\"prev.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\""+
    " alt=\"previous month\"></td>\n"+
    "</tr>\n</table>\n"
);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? The former is PHP, the latter seems to be Javascript

Comment: ummmm you **cannot** do `var str_buffer = new String (...` in PHP

Comment: You don't *call* an image.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why is there suddenly javascript? `+` is javascripts concatenate, not PHP's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to implement the method used in the PHP for calling a function, within the Javascript code?

If so, You need to enclose the Javascript segments within a PHP output statement.
Eg.

```
    echo 'var str_buffer = new String (
 "<table width=\"100%\">\n"+
    "<tr>\n <td>\n"+
    "<img src=\"' . $call->getSkinUrl('images/prev.gif'); . '\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\""+
    " alt=\"previous month\"></td>\n"+
    "</tr>\n</table>\n"
);';
```

Aditionally, you will need to implement the class/object on the page where you want to use it.

Comment: Sorry for all the fuss about the question. This is actually the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just an FYI, you shouldn't use `new String` in JavaScript.  When you use `new String` you have an object, not a string.  So, `"ABC" === "ABC"`, but `"ABC" !== new String("ABC")`.